# how to get index page in magento while using event observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

when am creating a customer in magento (before creating the event observer),

after click on the register the following screen will appear.

[image]

after adding observer,the page link goes to 
  **http://mgstore/customer/account/createpost/**
 and gives output of the observer.
how can i skip this step,and how can i get normal page like dashboard given above.

Comment: Remove the observer function from `config.xml`. Where is that event called from, which module/extension?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, remove this from `config.xml` file.

```
<events> 
    <customer_register_success> 
      <observers> 
       <Wli_Registrationdemo_customer_register_success> 
          <type>singleton</type> 
          <class>Wli_Registrationdemo_Model_Observer</class> 
          <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method> 
       </Wli_Registrationdemo_customer_register_success> 
      </observers> 
     </customer_register_success> 
</events>
```

Hope this helps.

**PS**

If this observer is also doing some other stuff other than redirecting then will need to remove codes from `observer.php` too.

Comment: i removed observer as per above in config.xml ,but it not works

Comment: did u refresh cache? Also can you add your `observer.php`?

Comment: yes,after refreshing the cache,it works,but observer.php will not affecting.

Comment: Right, cheers then, glad it helped.

Comment: thanks,but what about observer.php,its not working now

Comment: Can you add your observer.php please, will need to delete some codes only then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27637/discussion-between-rizwan-and-adarsh-khatri).